# Angular releases - put hard-coded version or github link in package.json?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material

My team at work has a fairly new angular app where we want to keep things up-to-date as much as possible, so our package.json has looked like this:

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
   "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
   ...
}
```

This has proved problematic since 3 times in the last few months we spend a few hours fixing random compile errors due to new versions of angular material (or something similar) being pushed out. Don't ask me why, but we could only solve the latest odd dependency error by putting in a specific version for the angular/material like so:

```
    "@angular/material": "7.0.0-beta.2",
```

... even though that is the latest version it should have been grabbing. I'm thinking we might just have to keep it like that.

My question is: ***Should we be leaving the link to the github latest version in there?*** Is that common practice? It'd be nice to always have our project automatically kept up to date, but with things breaking that makes it really hard.

In a larger sense, ***what's generally regarded as best practices to keep angular up to date***? Do we just have to go through every few months to manually update everything and test to make sure it all works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion (which might not be perfect for everyone) I think it's a bad idea.

For example, if you got your project with a nice continuous integration system, your tests might pass locally, and between the moment you tested locally and the moment the CI started to download the dependencies, something will have changed. Now imagine that you use the pipeline only as continuous deployment (which would be a really bad idea without tests), you could get major differences between your local project and the project on CI.

People have been fighting this for years and trying to pin the versions of the dependencies + versions of the sub dependencies in projects. Yarn had a huge success because of that and their `yarn.lock` file. Now npm does that too.

If you really want to keep your project up to date without really having to go through that process manually (which seems very risky for a UI lib), I'd say that the only way to be confident doing all of that is:

- having a lot of tests, because you'll be deploying things that might be broken otherwise
- having a lot of E2E tests and definitely some visual tool to check  regressions/screenshot diffing
- having some bot/automated checks that check whether a new version is available and if so, create a new commit, run the pipeline, merge only if everything is green

I'd say that's a lot of setup for not so much.
If you upgrade every month or every 2 months you'll be just fine.
(but nevertheless, you should still have a lot of tests, unit, integration, E2E and a CI system!) It's mostly the screenshot diffing that's kind of hard right now but hopefully we might get a proper support with Cypress in the next few months (?)

Comment: I think all of what you are saying here is spot on. We'll just have to figure out some way to update every few months or get an automated notice when a release comes out. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You're welcome, regarding the release you can either, keep an eye on Github (changelog or release tab), subscribe on Twitter to @releasebutler (bot Tweeting when it detects new releases on Github), use sometimes the `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest` command or for npm `ncu` https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates